# Dockerize Django application with mongoDB

Tags: django, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am working on Django web application which store the data in mongoDB database. When I run the docker using the docker-compose.yml file, it open the login page and gives the CSFR token error. Following are the logs of Django container:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 61ad29e66ee4fa015775e4b9, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>]>

[05/Dec/2021 21:13:23] "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 500 94504
```

Content of docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mongodb_container:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - django_data_container:/home/app/webapp  
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - mongodb_container
    depends_on:
      - mongodb_container
```

Can anyone tell me how I can communicate the Django with mongoDB using dockers?

Comment: Can you include your django database settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error:

> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017

we can tell that you are trying to connect to the `localhost` on port `27017`, but `localhost` will only address the django container itself. In order to connect to another container (mongodb), change the connection string or connection configuration in django settings to point to that other container's name. In your case you want to change `localhost` to `mongodb_container`.